# Compute $\oint_{|z-i|=1}(z^{42}+e^{137z})(\cos(\pi z)+\frac{47}{11}z^{13})dz$

Tags: complex-analysis

> Compute $\displaystyle\oint_{|z-i|=1}(z^{42}+e^{137z})(\cos(\pi z)+\frac{47}{11}z^{13})dz$

So I have the parametrisation $\gamma: [0,2\pi], t\mapsto i+\exp(it)$ and the 4 Integrals:

1. $\displaystyle\oint_{|z-i|=1}z^{42}\cos(\pi z)dz$
2. $\displaystyle\oint_{|z-i|=1}\frac{47}{11}z^{57}dz$
3. $\displaystyle\oint_{|z-i|=1}e^{137z}\cos(\pi z)dz$
4. $\displaystyle\oint_{|z-i|=1}\frac{47}{11}z^{13}e^{137z}dz$

Now, before I start any further thinking. Aren't all integral $0$ since all the functions are entire functions and the integrals are closed?

What prevents me from using Cauchy's formula for

$\displaystyle\oint_{|z-i|=1}f(z)dz=\displaystyle\oint_{|z-i|=1}\frac{f(z)(z-i)}{z-i}dz=f(i)(i-i)=0$?

Comment: You're right. The integrand is an entire function, so the closed integral is 0.

Comment: The integrand is an entire function, so integrating it over any closed contour yields zero.

Comment: Thanks. Any comment about my use of Cauchy's formula? Obviously I can't always do that. Does it work in this case? And if yes, why?

Comment: $f(z)(z-i)$ is entire, in particular, holomorphic in a domain containing the circle $|z-i|=1,$ so you can indeed use Cauchy's formula and get $2\pi i f(i)(i-i)=0.$